# In C#, what exact role do delegates play in event handling?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, delegates

I have gone through the documentation, various tutorials, lectures. It feels like I understand what exactly is a delegate but I am not able to figure out why do we need them in Event handling. We can also handle events by directly calling the event handling methods right, then is the use of doing it through delegates?
P.S Please don't be harsh on me.

Comment: _"We can also handle events by directly calling the event handling methods right"_ - and how would you do that without delegates? What will you use to represent a strongly typed reference to a method in C# (so you can add them as subscription to the event and then call it later)?